# When exporting a redux reducer Im getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

**UPDATE**: *I was not adding the slice to the actual store, Im now able to dispatch actions however the namePlaceholder constant still yields undefined*

When try to export my selector function I get an error:

[image]

This is the component code:

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
    changeName,
    componentTestSelector,
  } from './componentTestSlice';

export function ComponentTest(){
    const namePlaceholder = useSelector(componentTestSelector);//crashes app
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState('');

    return(
        <div>
            <label>New</label>
            <input
                aria-label="Set name"
                value={inputName}
                onChange={e => setInputName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
          aria-label="submit new name"
          onClick={() => dispatch(changeName())}
        >change it</button>
            <span >{namePlaceholder}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentTest
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is the Slice's code:

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const componentTest = createSlice({
    name: 'componentTest',
    initialState: {
        name: 'test name'
    },
    reducers:{
        changeName: (state, action) => {
            state.name = action.payload;
        },
    }
})

export const { changeName } = componentTest.actions;

export const componentTestSelector = state => state.componentTest.name;

export default componentTest.reducer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I replicated the Counter component in the example, if i comment out the namePlaceholder line the app runs, but well the state never changes

Comment: I've pored over these snippets and the docs and I don't see any overt issues (I'm familiar with react-redux, but not the newer toolkit). The error is saying that `state.componentTest` is undefined. Do you have the redux dev-tools extension installed in your browser so you can possibly verify/validate your redux state is populated? Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that others can live debug?

Comment: Here is my repo Drew https://github.com/marioperez25/redux-first-steps Ill try to replicate in a sandbox soon...

Comment: I cloned your repo into a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-feather-9uy9j you can fork it. Did your repo have the updated code you just mentioned in your edit?

Comment: Just push it! sorry 2 excited it worked

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be much simpler than you probably expected. You neglected to send the inputted name state value with the dispatched action.

```
export function ComponentTest() {
  const namePlaceholder = useSelector(componentTestSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <label>New</label>
      <input
        aria-label="Set name"
        value={inputName}
        onChange={(e) => setInputName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        aria-label="submit new name"
        onClick={() => dispatch(changeName(inputName))} // <-- pass name value
      >
        change it
      </button>
      <span>{namePlaceholder}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit when-exporting-a-redux-reducer-im-getting-a-typeerror-cannot-read-property-na]

Comment: Thanks or the help, but Im afraid this still returns the same error while exporting "componentTestSelector"

Comment: @MarioPerez What error specifically? I don't see any errors in my sandbox. The edits I made were importing the `componentTestSlice` reducer and added it to the root reducer in the store, and passing the name to the action creator.